# Убить процесс из PHP

Tags: php, linux, kill

Процесс нормально убивается из консоли командой:

```
$ kill $pid
```

В PHP пытаюсь убивать:

```
exec('kill' . $pid,$out,$status);
```

`status` возвращает 1. Процесс не удаляется. Права root. Почему не убивается процесс?

Comment: Попробуйте передать номер сигнала.

Comment: exec('kill -9 $pid',$out,$status); пробовал вот так. тоже не работает

Comment: По-вашему что выдает 'kill $pid' ?  Вероятно вы забыли что только двойные кавычки подставляют значение переменной.

Comment: Документацию пробовали читать? http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php

Comment: пробовал вместо переменной $pid подставлять число. не отрабатывает